# Searching windows registry (specifically) HKLM with powershell very slow

Tags: powershell, windows-registry

I've been doing searches on my registry and everything works well except HKLM. A search on HKLM takes hours and doesn't seem to work.

I'm using some powershell code [from here](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2006/07/12/how-do-i-search-the-registry-for-a-value-in-powershell/)

`gci . -rec -ea SilentlyContinue | % { if((get-itemproperty -Path $_.PsPath) -match “<SomeText>”) { $_.PsPath} }`

This is running as administrator on WinXP under a domain logged into both administrator as well as domain admin.

After a few expected security warnings for SAM and the like, it continues searching for hours--I could do better with F3 in regedit. It doesn't seem to find anything, either. Any ideas on why it's so slow?

Also, just as a side note, if I search HKU and HKLM, do I end up searching the whole registry (besides PERFORMANCE_DATA and DYN_DATA)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This questions was asked regarding the filesystem on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196937/how-to-speed-up-powershell-get-childitem-over-unc). I would imagine the same applies to using it for the registry. I linked to Lee Holmes blog post on PowerShell Team's blog.

I would expect you might get a quicker search using `REG.exe` with the `/QUERY` parameter.